# Deconstructing this format: AことはBことがあります

Tags: grammar, particle-は

I was doing an N5 test, and this construction came up:

山田さんは大変いいひとですよ。(Context)

> 何も悪いことは聞いたことがありません。(Construction in question)

While I understand the meaning alright (Nothing bad about 田中さん was heard), I do not understand the structure here. Particularly, how does は work here connecting `悪いこと` and `聞いたこと`? Why not simply say

`何も悪く聞いたことがありません`

instead, or is the meaning somehow different?

Hours of search hasn't turned up anything related. Is there any online resource I can refer to? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The こと

This is a case where thinking about it in English might actually help.

In English, one says *"I haven't heard any**thing** bad about someone"*.  The point here is that we need to have a noun as the object of the verb *hear*.

In Japanese, we're not just *"hearing badly"* about someone (悪く聞く), we're *"hearing **something** bad"* about someone.  That's where that first こと comes in (悪い​**[こ]{●}[と]{●}**​を聞く).

The second こと is part of the standard construction, `[VERB in た form]` + ことがある, referring to whether someone has had any experience of `[VERB]`, such as *"have you ever `[VERB]`ed?"*

#### The は

The は in your sample question replaces the を.  This construction uses は for emphasis, making the 悪いこと a kind of sub-topic within the overall topic of 山田さん.  The implication is that you haven't heard *anything bad*, though you may have heard other things.  This is often conveyed in English more through tone of voice.

For instance, タバコ​**[を]{●}**​吸いません just means neutrally that you don't smoke
 tobacco.  Using は instead, タバコ​**[は]{●}**​吸いません states that you don't smoke *tobacco*, but it could imply that you smoke other things, just not tobacco products.  As with many things in language, context is important in discerning the intended meaning.